# How to use python multiprocessing inside a function in a package?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function inside a package,the function is

```
from multiprocessing import Pool    

def sampling(p,q):
    f = Pool(6)
    total_frames=q
    ensemble_row=6
    ensemble_col=8
    frame_ensemble=[]
    ensemble_set=[]

    args1=[0,80,total_frames,p]
    args2=[80,160,total_frames,p]
    args3=[160,240,total_frames,p]
    args4=[240,320,total_frames,p]
    args5=[320,400,total_frames,p]
    args6=[400,480,total_frames,p]
    args_list=[args1,args2,args3,args4,args5,args6]

    # parallising part


    ensemble_set = f.map(core_ensembling,args_list)

    return ensemble_set
```

This package is imported and used in another python program. But i am getting the following error:

> NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: I don't know the module, but if the error type is `NotImplementedError`, either you implement it yourself, or you wait for it to be implemented...

Comment: Why are there two `Pool` objects?

Comment: Why do you need to include `p` in the `args*`? What is the mapped function using it for?

Comment: @fjarri I have edited,core_ensembling do some work on args1,2..6.and return a list for each args.

Comment: What is the value `p` and what is `core_ensembling`?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems now. Could you provide a self-contained runnable code that reproduces the error?